# Django Python Machine Test

Tags: python, post, django-rest-framework, django-templates, get

Consider the following scenario where we have 3 entities in our system.

1. User
2. Client
3. Project

We have the number of users registered in our system.

You can use Django’s default admin template to create/register users but not other entities or you can make REST APIs for users as well if you want.

You have to perform the following tasks :

1. Register a client
2. Fetch clients info
3. Edit/Delete client info
4. Add new projects for a client and assign users to those projects.
5. Retrieve assigned projects to logged-in users.

Things to consider :

1. The system has many users.
2. The system has many clients.
3. A client can have many projects
4. A single project can be assigned to many users.

---

Given are the examples of REST APIs you have to build.

List of all clients

GET /clients/

[

{

```
 'id' : 1,

 'client_name' : 'Nimap',

 'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',

'created_by' : 'Rohit'
```

},

{

```
 'id' : 2,

 'client_name' : 'Infotech',

'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',

 'created_by' : 'Rohit'
```

}

]

---

Create a new client

POST /clients/

Input = {

'client_name' : 'company A'

}

Output = {

```
'id' : 3,

     'client_name' : 'company A',

'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',

'created_by' : 'Rohit'
```

}

---

Retrieve info of a client along with projects assigned to its users

GET /clients/:id

{

```
     'id' : 2,

'client_name' : 'Infotech',

'projects' : [

             {

                                     'id' : 1,

                                     'name' : 'project A'

             }

]

'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',

'created_by' : 'Rohit'

'updated_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',
```

}

---

Update info of a client

PUT-PATCH /clients/:id

Input = {

```
            'client_name' : 'company A'
```

}

Output = {

```
                 'id' : 3,

            'client_name' : 'company A',

            'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',

            'created_by' : 'Rohit',

            'updated_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30'
```

}

---

DELETE /clients/:id

The response status should be 204.

---

Create a new project

POST clients/:id/projects/

Here you do not need to create any new user but assign already registered users.

retrieve client id from the url and assign it to a project.

Input = {

'project_name' : 'Project A'

'users' : [

```
 {

     'id' : 1,

     'name' : 'Rohit'

 }
```

]

}

Output = {

```
     'id' : 3,

     'project_name' : 'Project A',

'client' : 'Nimap'

'users' :         [

             {

                                     'id' : 1,

                                     'name' : 'Rohit'

             }

]

'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30'

'created_by' : 'Ganesh'
```

}

---

List of all projects assigned to the logged-in user

GET /projects/

[

{

```
'id' : 1,

 'project_name' : 'Project A',

'created_at' : '2019-12-24T11:03:55.931739+05:30',

'created_by' : 'Ganesh'
```

},

{

I'm messed up right now,I'm new in django and have no idea about this assestment, tomorrow is the last day to submit this assestment. I need a proper code for this question please help